# Convert python list with line seperator (\n) to multiple rows in text file

Tags: python, list, export-to-csv

Python list :

```
['date_stamp', var-Session k_1_p90,var-Session k_p50,var-Session k_1_p99,var-Session k_1_p50,var-Session k_p99,var-Session k_n,var-Session k_1_n,var-Session k_p90\n', '2018-01-27T08:00:00.000Z,11.24738,14.52714223443346,152.9584864275955,57.0742794485366,2302.579844821834,7.0030523E7,7.0046544E7,54.7883473905\n', '2018-01-28T08:00:00.000Z,19.5676560165637,14.08600105483512,146.269316836613,38.4980853428318,2360.6314485913717,6.2752528E7,6.27673E7,57.5012673249\n', '2018-01-25T08:00:00.000Z,85.2086139422115,14.12775262408616,1635.32595576107,31.8109592470369,2352.0700540932644,4.820291E7,4.8217209E7,7.8476639727\n']
```

When I print this to a txt file, it prints out as following with a leading comma in front of each line start from the second line, I trying to get this data in to a csv format: 
[image]
expecting the following output :

[image]

Comment: I tried converting the list to string using str1 = ','.join(input_list) , in an attempt to replace "\n," characters with just "\n". But it prints out the same way as it prints out in the text file.

Comment: You should put that information into your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is like this,

```
list = ['date_stamp, var-Session k_1_p90,var-Session k_p50,var-Session k_1_p99,var-Session k_1_p50,var-Session k_p99,var-Session k_n,var-Session k_1_n,var-Session k_p90\n', '2018-01-27T08:00:00.000Z,11.24738,14.52714223443346,152.9584864275955,57.0742794485366,2302.579844821834,7.0030523E7,7.0046544E7,54.7883473905\n', '2018-01-28T08:00:00.000Z,19.5676560165637,14.08600105483512,146.269316836613,38.4980853428318,2360.6314485913717,6.2752528E7,6.27673E7,57.5012673249\n', '2018-01-25T08:00:00.000Z,85.2086139422115,14.12775262408616,1635.32595576107,31.8109592470369,2352.0700540932644,4.820291E7,4.8217209E7,7.8476639727\n']
 f = open('sample.txt', 'w+')
 for list_element in list:
     f.write('%s' %list_element)
 f.close()
```